# How do programs access ~/Library/Mail under OSX 10.14 (Mojave)

Tags: terminal, mail.app, email

After upgrading to 10.14, I am unable to access the `~/Library/Mail` directory, either as the user or as root.

```
[~/Library/Mail 14:01:42]$ ls -l
ls: .: Operation not permitted
[~/Library/Mail 14:04:11]$
```

So that's pretty weird. It happens even if I am root.

No system flags are set on the directory.

So presumably, this is another system integrity or sandboxing thing. Unfortunately, I have code that wants to access the sqlite3 database inside the `~/Library/Mail` directory.  So how do I grant my software access to my mail?

This seems to be related to the 10.14 privacy protections.

Comment: How are you trying to access it? it works for me if I `cd ~/Library/Mail` then `ls -l` & how are you acquiring 'root' ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me! Either as the ordinary user or as root. Which OS version are you using? I'm using 10.14.1

Comment: Oh, I access root with `sudo bash`

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. See the answer below.

Answer (score 12):

## Full Disk Access

Add your application or tool to the **Full Disk Access** list within **System Preferences > Security & Privacy**.

This is related to the new macOS Privacy Protections in 10.14, aka Mojave.

If you want programs launched from Terminal to be able to access `~/Library/Mail`, you will need to add them to the Full Disk Access list (below). I originally added Terminal and still couldn't access the folder. It turns out that I use iTerm2, and not Terminal. That had to be added also.

[image]